# How to save telegram python variable value to local database?

Tags: python, mysql, database, bots, telegram

Sorry, i am newbie in python

i have problem to save variable in python bot telegram into localhost. How to save the value of python bot telegram variable into the local database?
 Like the following variables

```
user.sex,user.age, user.q27
```

I've made a connection like the this

```
con = pymysql.connect(db="python", user="root", passwd="",host="localhost",port=3306,autocommit=True) 
cur = con.cursor()
```

And try to execute the query in process_data

```
chat_id = message.chat.id
  q27 = message.text
  user = user_dict[chat_id]
  user.q27 = q27

  cur.execute("INSERT INTO diagnosa (sex, age, jawaban) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)" (user.sex,user.age, user.q27))

  msg = bot.send_message(chat_id, 'Nice to meet you ' + user.name + '\n Age:' + str(user.age) + '\n Sex:' + user.sex + '\n jawaban:' + user.q27 )
  bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, send_end)
```

Complete code

```
import pymysql
```

import time

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

API_TOKEN = ''

bot = telebot.TeleBot(API_TOKEN)

user_dict = {}

con = pymysql.connect(db="python", user="root", passwd="",host="localhost",port=3306,autocommit=True)
cur = con.cursor()


class User:
  def __init__(self, name):
  self.name = name
  self.age = None
  self.sex = None
  self.q27 = None

@bot.message_handler(commands=['help', 'start'])

@bot.message_handler(commands=['help', 'start'])
def send_welcome(message):
  msg = bot.reply_to(message, """\
Siapa Nama Anda?
""")
  bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_name_step)

def process_name_step(message):
  try:
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    name = message.text
    user = User(name)
    user_dict[chat_id] = user
    msg = bot.reply_to(message, 'Berapakah umur anda?')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_age_step)
  except Exception as e:
    bot.reply_to(message, 'Kesalahan name step')

def process_age_step(message):
  try:
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    age = message.text
    if not age.isdigit():
    msg = bot.reply_to(message, 'Umur haruslah sebuah angka. Berapakah usia anda?')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_age_step)
    return
    user = user_dict[chat_id]
    user.age = age
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(one_time_keyboard=True)
    markup.add('Pria', 'Wanita')
    msg = bot.reply_to(message, 'Apakah jenis kelamin anda?', reply_markup=markup)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_q27_step)
  except Exception as e:
    bot.reply_to(message, 'Kesalahan age step')

def process_data(message):
  try:
   chat_id = message.chat.id
   q27 = message.text
   user = user_dict[chat_id]
   user.q27 = q27

   cur.execute("INSERT INTO diagnosa (sex, age) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)" (user.sex,user.age, user.q27))

   msg = bot.send_message(chat_id, 'Nice to meet you ' + user.name + '\n Age:' + str(user.age) + '\n Sex:' + user.sex + '\n jawaban:' + user.q27 )
   bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, send_end)
  except Exception as e:
   bot.reply_to(message, 'oooops')

def send_end(message):
   msg = bot.reply_to(message,"""Byeee""")

bot.polling()
```

Comment: You're missing a comma in `%s)" (user.sex` it should be `...%s)", (user.sex,...`

Comment: You possibly also need `con.commit()` after the INSERT statement. But you haven't been specific in what isn't working as expected.

Comment: Adding all the extra code but still not providing any indication of what the issue is has just made the question even more unclear.

Comment: Thank you so much for trying to help roganjosh. 
In the code, in the process query step_data not executable and directly go to the execption that bring up the "oooops" value in Telegram replay

Comment: finally I get the solution of the problem
I do not need `cur = con.cursor ()`. Before writing the query we need to write

`with con.cursor () as cursor:
             sql = "query"
             cursor.execute (sql)

         con.commit ()
         con.close ()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I get the solution of the problem. I do not need `cur = con.cursor ()`.

Before writing the query, we need to write

```
with con.cursor () as cursor:

sql = "query" cursor.execute (sql)
con.commit ()
con.close ()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
pip install pymysql
```

---

```
import pymysql
import time

con = pymysql.connect(db="db", user="root", passwd="",host="h",port=3306,autocommit=True)
#cur = con.cursor()
with con.cursor () as cursor:
     sql = "stmt"
     cursor.execute (sql)
     con.commit()
     con.close()
```